# How do I query Salesforce object sharing settings?

Tags: apex, soql, sharing

We have data in our in-house systems relating to Salesforce object records. We need to replicate the Salesforce permissions on the corresponding records in our systems.

I've been investigating retrieving the org-wide default sharing settings through Apex and am having the following issues:

- I can get the default access for internal users for most standard objects from the Organization object; however, I cannot find a value for the Order object.
- I cannot find the default access for external users for any object.
- I cannot find the status of the check boxes (e.g., grant access to hierarchies, portal user visibility, etc.).
- I cannot find where the configuration for the object sharing rules is stored.

I've checked the ObjectPermissions object and the *CustomObject*__Share objects, but those object don't hold the above information.

Can anyone point me to where I can query this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [retrieve()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_retrieve.htm) call, which lets you specify metadata to get information you're looking for, including the org wide defaults for a given object, grant access via hierarchy options, etc. Note that some objects don't have sharing; they are controlled by the parent object(s) instead. For most of what you want, you will retrieve [CustomObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm), which also returns standard objects. If you also want Field Level Security, you must also retrieve [Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) and [PermissionSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_permissionset.htm).

Comment: Hmm. I was hoping for a SOQL query rather than an API call as we need to check the values frequently. Those settings don't change often; maybe I will cache the values we need into custom objects and refresh them either on demand or on a schedule. In any case, thanks for the information. It will take me a while to find where everything I need is stored, but I have the data now.

Answer (score 3):

You can query the Tooling API object [`EntityDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm#!) to get information about internal and external sharing models:

```
SELECT NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName, ExternalSharingModel, InternalSharingModel FROM EntityDefinition
```

However, the other information you're interested in (as sfdcfox described) will probably require the Metadata API.

Comment: Thanks. That information is also available in the _CustomObject_ method of the Metadata API which @sfdcfox pointed out above. I'll probably go with that just because the rest of the info is also exposed through that same API, but I appreciate the tip.